# Google map coordinates in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get the current position on google map. The code is working fine when I get the coordinates, but these coordinates I want to get and google map toom because right now, coordinates are static for google map.

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';
import { withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Marker } from "google-map-react"
import { InfoWindow } from 'google-map-react';
import Geolocation from 'react-geolocation'


const AnyReactComponent = ({ text }) => <div>{ text }</div>;



export default class Map extends Component {


  static defaultProps = {
    center: { lat: 40.7446790, lng: -73.9485420 },
    zoom: 11
  }
render() {
    return (
      <Geolocation
  render={({
    fetchingPosition,
    position: { coords: { latitude, longitude } = {} } = {},
    error,
    getCurrentPosition
  }) =>
    <div>
      <button onClick={getCurrentPosition}>Get Position</button>
      {error &&
        <div>
          {error.message}
        </div>}
      <pre>
        latitude: {latitude}
        longitude: {longitude}
      </pre>
      <div className='google-map' style={{ height: '80vh', width: '100%' }}>

        <GoogleMapReact

          defaultCenter={ this.props.center }
          defaultZoom={ this.props.zoom }>
          <AnyReactComponent
            lat={ latitude }
            lng={ longitude }
            text={ 'Wheres Waldo?' }
          />
        </GoogleMapReact>
      </div>
    </div>}
/>
    )
  }
}
```

With Geolocation I get very well coordinates, but these coordinates want to set in:

```
static defaultProps = {
    center: { lat: 40.7446790, lng: -73.9485420 },
    zoom: 11
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must define a state for your `<Map>` component, which will store your current coordinates.
Then, you should pass the state to your `GoogleMapReact` component.

In order to set the state with the coordinates found by the Geolocation services, you can use `onSuccess` callback (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-geolocation#onsuccess-function):

```
<Geolocation
    onSuccess={this.geoSuccess}
    ...
/>
```

The `geoSuccess` function is:

```
geoSuccess = position => { 
   let coords = {
     lat: position.coords.latitude,
     lng: position.coords.longitude
   }

   this.setState({
     center: coords
   })
};
```

Demo here:
https://43qv620770.codesandbox.io/

The full code can be found here (the file Map.js):
https://codesandbox.io/s/43qv620770

Comment: andreivictor, please can you show your code for link that you have put in description? I'm trying in this form but doesn't work. Maybe I'm following wrong procedure. Btw, thanks for your answer :)

Comment: hello, I've updated my answer with a link where you can find the full code. You have to look in the file Map.js.

Comment: please be aware that the demo will not work in edit mode (https://codesandbox.io/s/43qv620770), you have to check the full-page demo (https://43qv620770.codesandbox.io/).

Comment: andreivictor thank you so much. It's work very well :)